# Apple MainStage audio output device changes automatically after some time

Tags: audio

I am using Apple MainStage 3.5 and I route the Audio Output to a [Loopback](https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/) virtual device. And this works like a charm. Until it switches to another device after some inactivity.

I tried another Loopback device, but the same thing keeps happening. Does anybody have an idea how to tell MainStage to not switch devices? I thought that setting the `hot-plug behavior` to `do nothing` was the key. But it does not seem to work.

I did some Googling, but could not find an answer to my question. I hope somebody knows.

[image]

Comment: Does it always switch to the same other device? Is this ever after some 'downtime' - sleep, screensaver etc? Where is Loopback routing (idk if that's important but who knows)?

Comment: No it does not always switch to the same device. It switches to a device connected, which could be one of the headphone or monitor. it is lways a hardware one. It is definitely after screensaver. So I assume loopback becomes inactive. But I expect Mainstage to still keep it, even though it is temporarily not there.

Comment: I'd be inclined to ask Rogue Amoeba directly. They're really smart cookies & quick to reply to enquiries. I've had them come back with answers within the day (though my particular issue couldn't be fixed, they explained in good detail why that was).

Comment: Thx. I will do that. I assumed, when writing down, that this was an Apple thing. But your questioning makes Rogue Amoeba a better candidate

Comment: Come back & drop in an answer if you get one. Could be very useful to future Googlers. (& I'd be interested to know too ;)) Wish you luck.

Comment: Done and thx for the help @Tetsujin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some frequent contact with [Rogue Amoeba](https://rogueamoeba.com) we came to the following solution.
Strictly speaking is this not an answer to the original question, but a workaround.
I used the Loopback device to connect to Audio Hijack, but another solution is to select System Setting as Audio Output in MainStage. Then I captured the MainStage application in Audio Hijack instead of the Loopback device. Thus circumventing to whole need for Loopback as an input device into Audio Hijack.

BTW I still use Loopback to connect the Audio Hijack output further in the chain.